# What is the best configuration for azure Backup Vaults service..

Tags: azure

Hello i want to know about the Backup Vaults which is an azure service.

Can anyone please tell me the best configuration,Like i mean while i will configure the Backup Vaults service of azure then what configuration i will keep so that i will get the best performance.